# Swift Dictionary: Can't completely remove entry

Tags: swift, swift-playground, swift-dictionary

I have a Swift dictionary and I am trying to completely remove an entry. My code is as follows:

```
import UIKit

var questions: [[String:Any]] = [
    [
        "question": "What is the capital of Alabama?",
        "answer": "Montgomery"
    ],
    [
        "question": "What is the capital of Alaska?",
        "answer": "Juneau"
    ]
 ]

var ask1 = questions[0]
var ask2 = ask1["question"]

print(ask2!) // What is the capital of Alabama?

questions[0].removeAll()

ask1 = questions[0] // [:]
ask2 = ask1["question"] // nil - Should be "What is the capital of Alaska?"
```

I used questions[0].removeAll() to remove the entry but it leaves an empty entry. How can I completely remove an entry so that there is no trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this behaviour, you are telling to the compiler that removes all the elements in a `Dictionary` and it's working fine:

```
questions[0].removeAll()
```

But you're declaring an `Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>` or in shorthand syntax `[[String: Any]]` and you need to remove the entry from your array too if you want to remove the `Dictionary`, see the following code:

```
var questions: [[String: Any]] = [
   [
    "question": "What is the capital of Alabama?",
    "answer": "Montgomery"
   ],
   [
    "question": "What is the capital of Alaska?",
    "answer": "Juneau"
   ]
]

var ask1 = questions[0]
var ask2 = ask1["question"]

print(ask2!) // What is the capital of Alabama?

questions[0].removeAll()

questions.removeAtIndex(0) // removes the entry from the array in position 0

ask1 = questions[0] // ["answer": "Juneau", "question": "What is the capital of Alaska?"]
ask2 = ask1["question"] // "What is the capital of Alaska?"
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: `ask1 = questions[0]` is *not* `[:]` in your second line from the end of the code.

Comment: @MartinR Yes you're right my mistake I forget to update the value from the Playground, thanks, fixed